# Matlab codes to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

```
 % uniform patterns for neighboring points with 8
    U8File = importdata('UniformLBP8.txt');
    BinNum = U8File(1, 1);
    nDim = U8File(1, 2); %dimensionality of uniform patterns
    Code = U8File(2 : end, :);
    clear U8File;
```

Could anybody please explain these codes and possibly its equivalent implementation in C++? Thank you.

Comment: All this does is read a 2 column text file. The first line is a header with column 1 storing the `BinNum` whatever that means and column 2 stores the `nDim` which the code states is the "imensionality of uniform patterns". `Code` is then a matrix (or 2D array in C++) with all the following lines until the `end` of the document.

Comment: @Dan Got it. Unfortunatedly, you wont find anyone in this place to write the code for you, so good luck ;)